# Should we make extra effort at preventing replay attack for HTTPS enabled web application?

Tags: tls

> SSL/TLS channel itself is protected against replay attack

Assume we have to build a very secure web application and it must be HTTPS enabled, is it necessary to implement nonce or timestamp or other mechanism to prevent this attack?

Answer (score 1):

TLS  usually reliably prevents replay at the TLS level. The exception is the TLS 1.3 0-RTT handshake which should therefore not be used for requests where replaying is a problem (i.e. usually POST, requests with parameters...) - see [Introducing Zero Round Trip Time Resumption (0-RTT)](https://blog.cloudflare.com/introducing-0-rtt/) for more information.

But this is only relevant for replay of the exact encrypted bytes, i.e. some attacker sniffing on the network, capturing the traffic and replaying it. TLS does not prevent a replay at the application level, like someone resubmitting the same form again, reloading the web page ... If this is a problem for your specific use case you need to handle it at the application level no matter if you use HTTPS or plain HTTP.